# Extending Ruby with C++: Asynchronous callbacks from C++ to Ruby

Tags: c++, ruby, callback

I have some problem with writing Ruby C++ extension.
I have some C++ lib with sources. It have such function by documentation:

```
class MyConversation : public Conversation
  {
  public:
    typedef DRef<MyConversation, Conversation> Ref;
    typedef DRefs<MyConversation, Conversation> Refs;
    MyConversation(unsigned int oid, SERootObject* root) : Conversation(oid, root) {};

    void OnMessage(const MessageRef & message);
  };

  void MyConversation::OnMessage(const MessageRef & message)
  {
    // Message handling goes here
  };
```

In function MyConversation::OnMessage come messages from C++ library. I want send this messages to ruby extension, like this:

```
  void MyConversation::OnMessage(const MessageRef & message)
  {
    //some code catch here messages
  };
```

in ruby I simple want call:

```
listener = Object.new
listener.messages do |message|
  # As I understand Thread.current != Thread.main
end
```

How to do this? I completed functions, which call c++ from ruby, but how to do such thing I don't understand (I have weak knowledge about c and c++).

Thanks for the help!